# Run Startup Script as another Windows user on Google Compute Engine

Tags: windows, google-cloud-platform, cmd, google-compute-engine

I need to run my startup script as the admin user on Windows. Currently I have this:

```
vm.create({
  ...config,
  metadata: {
    items: [
      {
        key: "windows-startup-script-cmd",
        value: "cd /Users/admin/Documents && whoami >> log.txt",
      },
    ],
  },
});
```

This creates a log.txt with the current user which is `nt authority\system` and not the default user that you set up at Google Compute instances.

Has anyone used Windows on Google Compute Engine an successfully run a startup script as another user?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The account `nt authority\system` is a built-in system account that is part of the Administrators group. This account is not a user. Google Compute Engine instances run startup scripts as this account.

Your question is not clear on what you mean by `Administrator` account. This term is often used to mean a) The User Account named Administrator and b) An account with elevated permissions.

The startup system account is an Administrator, but it is not the user account named Administrator. These are different concepts. I do not recommend that you run scripts that require access to the user named Administrator. Instead, design your startup scripts to perform the tasks required as part of the system account.

Note that administrator accounts can have any name. The usage of `Administrator` is a convention only. Startup scripts are not logged in as users, so your goal to run the startup script as the logged-in user (which is not logged in at that point in time) is not possible. You must know the username in advance, the username must have a password and must be enabled. None of which exist on the first startup of a new instance.

You can schedule a task to run as any username using the `schtasks` command from a startup script. The user account must be enabled and have a password.

[Windows Schtasks.exe](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/taskschd/schtasks)

Comment: Thank you for this answer. I ended up looking into the Task Scheduler and found that GCEStartup was running as `nt authority\system`. I changed the user running GCEStartup to my own administrator account. The reason I didn't want to add my own scheduled task was that I needed the script to be sent through GCE as a string as it is created dynamically.

Comment: Hey @antoniozzo, how did you change the user running GCEStartup?

Answer (score 0):

Please review Google documentation [1] which outlines how to providing a startup script stored on Cloud Storage to a new instance or applying a startup script to running instances.

To do that you can create a .ps1 file and storing it into a cloud storage bucket.
Then call it from following gcloud command:

gcloud compute instances create example-windows-instance --scopes storage-ro \
    --metadata windows-startup-script-url=gs://bucket/startupscript.ps1

Note: To avoid inconsistency of && in Powershell change your startup script to:
cd /Users/admin/Documents ; whoami >> log.txt

[1] https://cloud.google.com/compute/docs/startupscript#providing_a_startup_script

Answer (score 0):

Change task user, then reboot the machine.

```
& schtasks.exe /change /tn GCEStartup /RU $username /RP $password

& shutdown.exe /r /f /t 0
```